# Is there a way to 'bind' Shiny UI components using R markdown?

Tags: r, shiny

Here's what I'm working with:
[image: Image of problem at hand]

I'm trying to make the sidebar contents change upon switching the top navigation tabs. So if Output 1 tab is active then the sidebar shows Output 1-related content. If Output 2 tab is active then sidebar shows Output 2-related content. Is this possible in R markdown? Thanks.

**SRC:**

```
---
title: "An Idiot's Dashboard"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    source_code: embed
---



Sidebar 1 {.sidebar}
=====================================
Output 1's side bar.


Output 1:
=====================================



## Row 1

### Thing 1


### Thing 2



Row 2
-------------------------------------

### Thing 3



Output 2:
=====================================

Row 1
-------------------------------------

### Thing 4


### Thing 5



Row 2
-------------------------------------

### Thing 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this took a lot longer for me to figure this out than it should.
Essentially, relegate

```
Sidebar 1 {.sidebar}
=====================================
```

to:

```
Output 1
===========================================

Sidebar 1 {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------
```

then do:

```
OUtput 2
===========================================

Sidebar 2{.sidebar}
-------------------------------------
```

and it works!